# Using PowerShell to run a remote script

Tags: powershell

I have searched several sites to try to figure out how to run a PowerShell script on a remote machine.  I have been using the following command:`Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath "C:\Temp\test.ps1"` however I get an error back saying the file doesn't exist.  However I can search the same machine trough powershell and see that in fact it is there.  Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

[image: View of powershell winodw]

Both of the answers below fixed the problem of it not finding the script, however now it looks like it runs the script, but nothing happens on the local machine:

[image]

The test.ps1 script has the following code:
 `cscript C:\Temp\queryTest.vbs`.
The queryTest.vbs file has this code:
`

```
sysdate = "1/1/2015"
Dim e
Dim wb
Dim sheet
Set e = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
e.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\testbook.xlsx")
Set wb = e.ActiveWorkbook
Set Sheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
sheet.Cells(1,1).Value = sysdate
set sheet = nothing
wb.Save
wb.close
Set wb=nothing
e.Quit
Set e = Nothing
```

`

Nothing is writing in the excel file when i run test.ps1 remotely, however if i kick if off on the local machine it runs fine.  I've tried calling both the ps1 script and the vbs script from powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-FilePath` parameter of Invoke-Command is looking at the LOCAL filesystem, not the filesystem on the remote server. It is intended as a way to run complex commands remotely, by reading a local script file, serializing its contents, and then deserializing and executing those commands on the remote host. You could just change your `-FilePath` parameter to `-Scriptblock {& "C:\Temp\Test.ps1"}`, or, if you copy the script to your own local C:\Temp directory, it will run as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

The script file `"C:\Temp\test.ps1"` are you supposing it to be on remote machine?
If yes then try to give `"\\machineName\C$\temp\test.ps1"`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem I'm having was a problem in one of my scripts.  Opening a new question for the issue I'm now observing.